# Regex to extract all characters before the second dash/hyphen

Tags: php, regex

I'm in need of a php regular expression that will extract all of the characters BEFORE the second dash/hyphen in this type of string:

EDM-2112-100-2013  ==> EDM-2112
ABCD-2002-100-2014 ==> ABCD-2002

And, I know that I can use various string manipulation functions to accomplish this (substr, etc.) but it has to be a regular expression.  We are using the regular expression to define customer specific rules that get evaluated as data is presented.  When the data is presented, we apply the customer specific regular expression from the database to the inbound data and then work with the extracted data.

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: Check this out http://regex101.com/r/yM0hT2/1

Comment: Split string, re-attach after split?

Comment: hex494D49 - that's a cool resource...thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You're welcome, next time I'll add an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
\A(?:[^-]++-??){2}
```

**pattern details:**

```
\A            # anchor for the start of the string
(?:           # open a non-capturing group
    [^-]++    # all that is not an hyphen (possessive)
    -??       # optional hyphen (lazy)
){2}          # repeat the group 2 times
```

I admit that this pattern is a little tricky. It uses the fact that the [possessive quantifier](http://regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) makes mandatory the hyphen in the first occurence even if the quantifier is lazy. In the second occurence, the hyphen is not matched.

You can write more simply: `\A[^-]+-[^-]+`

If you want to check if there is a second hyphen after the match, you only need to add this [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the end of one of the two patterns: `(?=-)`

Comment: Thank you for this and for the thorough explanation.  The developer who wrote the code that interprets the expression is only evaluating the second element of the matches array (matches[1]).  Is there a way that I can modify the expression to return both elements [0] and [1]?

Comment: @MBrianDunson: yes, put the whole pattern inside parenthesis. And if you use the lookahead, remove it, and add an hyphen outside the parenthesis.